How to get repeated headings using longtable inside mdframed?
This is my first post.  I have been trying to use longtable within the mdframed environment using each of \endfirsthead, \endhead, \endfoot and \endlastfoot.  Within mdframed the headings and footings do not repeat.
There is an almost identical question asked previously - how to get longtable in mdframed to show more than firsthead? but there was no answer that I could identify.
In my MWE there are 3 tables:

Table 1 - longtable outside an mdframed environment.  All headings and footings function correctly.
Table 2 - longtable inside an mdframed environment.  No headings and footings other than the start of the table.  The table content is exactly the same as Table 1.
Table 3 - longtable inside an mdframed environment.  No headings and footings other than the start of the table.  The table content was expanded to ensure that there were more rows than a single page.  The result is different to Table 2 because page breaks occur at the same row counts as Table 1 but the headings and footings remain absent.

The following is my MWE (hopefully it is satisfactory):
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

    \newmdenv[              %
    frametitle=A Frame,     %
    frametitlerule=true,    %
    linewidth=1pt,          %
    linecolor=yellow,       %
    leftmargin=0in,         %
    rightmargin=0in,        %
    ]{mdf_com}

\begin{longtable}{| c | c | c |}
    \caption{A Caption}\label{tab:table1} \\ \hline
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\ \hline \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{A Caption (cont.)} \\ \hline
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\ \hline \endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline \endfoot
    \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ \hline \endlastfoot
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    \pagebreak Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    \pagebreak Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline     
\end{longtable}


\begin{mdf_com}
    \begin{longtable}{| c | c | c |}
        \caption{A Caption}\label{tab:table2} \\ \hline
        Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\ \hline \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{A Caption (cont.)} \\ \hline
        Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\ \hline \endhead
        \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline \endfoot
        \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ \hline \endlastfoot
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        \pagebreak Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        \pagebreak Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline     
    \end{longtable}
\end{mdf_com}

\begin{mdf_com}
    \begin{longtable}{| c | c | c |}
        \caption{A Caption}\label{tab:table3} \\ \hline
        Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\ \hline \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{A Caption (cont.)} \\ \hline
        Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\ \hline \endhead
        \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline \endfoot
        \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ \hline \endlastfoot
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        \pagebreak Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        \pagebreak Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
        Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline     
    \end{longtable}
\end{mdf_com}

\end{document}

I know that the previous question was unanswered in 2015 but am hopeful that package improvements since then may improve the likelihood of a solution.

AFAIK the problem is still the same as told in the comment to the linked question: Both, mdframed and longtable use their own page break algorithm not only to break the contents but also to add extra material before and after the page break. And these two algorithms collide. A combination of both would be needed. Maybe a feature request to the tcolorbox package would be helpful. But because it could be a complicated thing to do, don't expect a quick solution.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

@cabohah, Thank you for letting me know.  I will look at the [tag:tcolorbox] package as you suggest.  I admit that I'm not familiar with that package.  Meanwhile I will try other approaches.
